# ASP.NET invalid base64 input. The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, httppostedfilebase

I tried to upload a photo to my controller, but it shows this error. However, the other page works fine. May I ask why? below is my code for view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageProfile", "Owner", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 <input type="file" id="profilePic" name="profilePic" />
}
```

The other view that works fine

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.photo3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="file" id="photoupload3" name="photoupload3" />
                        <img id="photo3"  style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The name of the input file is "profile1".
And in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ManageProfile(Owner owner, HttpPostedFileBase profilePic)
        {
            string name = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var dbOwner = _context.OwnerDB.Find(owner.ownerID);
            dbOwner.contact = owner.contact;
            dbOwner.email = owner.email;
            dbOwner.Name = owner.Name;
            dbOwner.password = owner.password;
            if (profilePic != null)
            {
                dbOwner.profilePic = new byte[profilePic.ContentLength];
                profilePic.InputStream.Read(dbOwner.profilePic, 0, profilePic.ContentLength);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",null);
        }
```

and the other controller works fine

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewRoom(Room room, HttpPostedFileBase photoupload, HttpPostedFileBase photoupload2, HttpPostedFileBase photoupload3)
        {
            var ownerName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            Owner owner = _context.OwnerDB.Where(o => o.Name == ownerName).FirstOrDefault();
            room.ownerID = owner.ownerID;
            if (photoupload != null)
            {
                room.photo1 = new byte[photoupload.ContentLength];
                photoupload.InputStream.Read(room.photo1, 0, photoupload.ContentLength);
            }
```

Stack trace
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j4bR.png)

View full code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageProfile", "Owner", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Owner</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ownerID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contact, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.profilePic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @{
                        if (Model.profilePic != null)
                        {
                            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.profilePic);
                            var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);


                            <img src='@imgsrc' width="300" height="300" class="reel"
                                 data-image='@imgsrc'
                                 data-stitched="600"
                                 data-frames="30"
                                 data-frame="15"
                                 data-rows="1"
                                 data-row="1"
                                 data-loops="false"
                                 alt="@Model.Name" />
                        }

                    }

                    <input type="file" id="profilePic" name="profilePic" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: whats the error and which line of code is it failing on? How are you creating your base64 encoded string and what does it also actually look like to be invalid?

Comment: I dont even know, the debug in the controller doesnt show anything, in fact it dont go into the controller function. The other page I do exactly same as this

Comment: Where is the Owner control that it expects? - I don't see it here and you're querying based off some id...

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: I have updated in the post, u find see it in the picture there shows no line throws exception

Comment: The full code of the view is included as well